# Loop through the set of elements of the same class and sequentially add/remove a class on an event change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small carousel on the landing page and I want to change the text block (title and content) whenever the slide changes. So I've made the 5 blocks that contain title & content, first of which is visible, while the rest have a `.hideme` class that simply sets `display:none;` Here's the **HTML** part:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 slider_riteside_holder">
     <div class="ngage_slide_ttl_and_info">
          <h2>Useful, Powerful <span>and Awesome!</span></h2>
          <p>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget nunc vitae
             tellus luctus ullamcorper. Nam porttitor ullamcorper felis at convallis. Aenean ornare
             vestibulum nisi fringilla lacinia. Nullam pulvinar sollicitudin velit id laoreet.
             Quisque non rhoncus sem.
          </p>
     </div>
     <div class="ngage_slide_ttl_and_info hideme">
          <h2>Great <span>Expectations</span></h2>
          <p>
             Goore ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget nunc vitae
             tellus luctus ullamcorper. Nam porttitor ullamcorper felis at convallis. Aenean ornare
             vestibulum nisi fringilla lacinias twat.
          </p>
     </div>
     <div class="ngage_slide_ttl_and_info hideme">
         <h2>Amazing Features <span>For You</span></h2>
         <p>
             Goore ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget nunc vitae
             tellus luctus ullamcorper. Nam porttitor ullamcorper felis at convallis. Aenean ornare
             vestibulum nisi fringilla lacinias twat.
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="ngage_slide_ttl_and_info hideme">
         <h2>Rain Your <span>Love Down</span></h2>
         <p>
             Goore ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget nunc vitae
             tellus luctus ullamcorper. Nam porttitor ullamcorper felis at convallis. Aenean ornare
             vestibulum nisi fringilla lacinias twat.
         </p>
     </div>
     <div class="ngage_slide_ttl_and_info hideme">
          <h2>Make America <span>Great Again!</span></h2>
          <p>
             Goore ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget nunc vitae
             tellus luctus ullamcorper. Nam porttitor ullamcorper felis at convallis. Aenean ornare
             svestibulum nisi fringilla lacinias twat.
          </p>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default ngage_learnmore_btn">Learn more</button>
</div>
```

So every time the slider changes (I've already bined the corresponding event), there should be a loop through all the elements with the class of `.ngage_slide_ttl_and_info` and show the upcoming information block by removing its `.hideme` class and passing to the previous block (i.e. hiding it). 
Here's the empty JS code of for the loop (I'm using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for carousel):

```
$('.p_slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){

    $(".ngage_slide_ttl_and_info").each(function() {

    });

});
```

How can I achieve achieve this? Maybe there are more logical and optimized ways to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share `JavaScript` code as well?

Comment: I've added the empty loop, thanks!

Comment: `.p_slider` where is it in HTML?

Comment: So @Balabeque you wants that we fill this loop with code for you?

Comment: @Balabeque `$('.p_slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){` we can get these all 4 parameter value with `beforeChange` not after change with after change we can get `slick, currentSlide` only;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
var elements = $(".ngage_slide_ttl_and_info");

$('.p_slider').on('afterChange', function(slick, currentSlide){
    /* Add hideme class to all elements */
    elements.addClass('hideme');

    /* remove hideme class from current slide index element */
    elements.eq(currentSlide).removeClass('hideme');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to manually loop. If the only thing you need it's to unhidden the current not-hidden element, and unhidden the next, you may only need to find them:

```
var $current = $(".ngage_slide_ttl_and_info:not(.hideme)")
$current.addClass("hideme"); /* add class */
$current.removeClass("hideme");  /* remove class */
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop you can try this:

```
$('.p_slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
         var current = $('.ngage_slide_ttl_and_info:visible');
         var nextDiv = $(current).next();
         $(current).addClass('hideme');
         $(nextDiv).removeClass('hideme');
});
```